# Not copying char arrays, function swap doesnt compile correctly and stringPtr is not modified

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char, strcpy

//In header file: class definition:

```
class myString
{
public:

        myString(void);
        myString(const char *str);

        myString(const myString &); //copy constructor 
        ~myString(void); //destructor

        void swap(myString &from);


private:

        char *stringPtr;
        int stringLen;
};
```

//in cpp file, defining them member functions

```
myString::myString(const char *str)
{
    stringLen = strlen(str);

    stringPtr = new char[stringLen+1];

    strcpy(stringPtr,str);
    cout << "constructor with parameter called"<<endl;
}

myString::myString(const myString &str)
{

    stringPtr = new char[str.stringLen +1];
    strcpy(stringPtr,str.stringPtr);
    cout << "copyconstructor"<<endl;
}


void myString::swap(myString &from)
{
    myString buffer(from);
    int lengthBuffer = from.stringLen;

    from = new char[stringLen+1];
    from.stringLen = stringLen;
    strcpy(from.stringPtr, stringPtr);


    stringPtr = new char[lengthBuffer+1];
    stringLen = lengthBuffer;
    strcpy(stringPtr,buffer.stringPtr);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify a reference. Even if you replace it with a pointer modifying a pointer will not modify an object pointed to. Instead you need to work through the reference - just swap the fields.

```
void myString::swap(myString &from)
{
    std::swap( stringLen, from.stringLen );
    std::swap( stringPtr, from.stringPtr );
}
```

the above is using std::swap() as suggested by [user sbi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140719/sbi) in comments. This is completely equivalent to the following (just for illustration, don't reinvent STL):

```
void myString::swap(myString &from)
    // First remember own length and pointer
    const int myOldLen = stringLen;
    char* myOldPtr = stringPtr;
    // now copy the length and pointer from that other string
    stringLen = from.stringLen;
    stringPtr = from.stringPtr;
    // copy remembered length and pointer to that other string
    from.StringLen = myOldLen;
    from.StringPtr = myOldPtr;
    // done swapping
}
```

Both will work even when called fro self-swapping:

```
myString string;
string.swap( string );
```

Comment: so, you're saying `void func(int & a) { a = 1; }` won't modify a?

Comment: With the added bonus that this is safe against exceptions arising from memory allocation.

Comment: @vava: from = new char[stringLen+1]; would compile but myString doesn't have operator=() so it will not.

Comment: @sharptooth, it has constructor, that accepts `char *` so it will be converted to `from = MyString(new char[stringLen + ])` and use default `operator=` to copy it.

Comment: @sharptooth: Why are you swapping yourself instead of calling `std::swap`? That's hilarious! -1

Comment: @sbi: Good point. I just not that familiar with STL, but you're right - that would be three times less code.

Comment: @sharptooth: `std::swap` is part of the standard library, but of that part of it that came from the STL. Nevertheless, I've now up-voted your answer.

Comment: Urgh. "...but _not_ of that part of it that came from the STL." Sigh.

Answer (score 1):

You have already gotten a few good answers concerning the errors in you `myString::swap()` function. Yet, I'd like to add another one. There's some many things wrong with that function, I first found it hard to think of where to begin. But then I realized that you fail on some fundamental issue which I'd like to point out:

As a convention, a function called `swap` is expected to perform its task

1. in O(1)
2. without ever throwing an exception.

(Yes, I know, there are exceptions: `std::tr1::array<>::swap()`. But those should be very well justified.) Your implementation fails on both accounts. It is O(n) (`strcpy`) and might throw an exception (`new`) -- and it does so unnecessarily and without justification.

When you look at `myString`, you'll see that it only has two pieces of member data, which both are of built-in type. That means swapping two objects of this class is *really* simple to do while keeping to the conventions mentioned above: just swap the member data. That's as simple as calling `std::swap` on them:

```
void myString::swap(myString &from)
{
  std::swap(this->stringPtr,from.stringPtr);
  std::swap(this->stringLen,from.stringLen);
}
```

This is will never fail (swapping two pointers and two integers cannot fail), executes in O(1), is very easy to understand (well, once you get a grip on that swapping, anyway; it is an idiomatic form of implementing a class-specific `swap` function), and consists of two lines of code calling something well-tested in the standard library instead of 8 lines of code doing error-prone (and, in your case, erroneous) manual memory management.

Note 1: Once you've done this, you should specialize `std::swap` to call your implementation for your class:

```
namespace std { // only allowed for specializing function templates in the std lib
  template<>
  inline void std::swap<myString>(myString& lhs, myString& rhs)
  {
    lhs.swap(rhs);
  }
```

Note 2: The best (simple, exception-safe, and self-assignment-safe) way to implement assignment for your class is to use its `swap`:

```
myString& myString::operator=(const myString& rhs)
{
   myString tmp(rhs); // invoke copy ctor
   this->swap(tmp); // steal data from temp and leave it with our own old data
   return *this;
} // tmp will automatically be destroyed and takes our old data with it
```

Comment: In assignment operator there should be check for self assignment .

Comment: @unknown: No, there shouldn't. The swap trick works just fine with self-assignment, and the additional `if` to optimize for the rare case would be a pessimization for the common case.

Answer (score 0):

`from = new char[stringLen+1];` should be `from.stringPtr = new char[stringLen+1];` . Also remember to free the previously allocated memory before allocating new one.

Answer (score 0):

Look closely at the line

```
from = new char[stringLen+1];
```

It is the same as

```
from = MyString(new char[stringLen+1]);
```

so your constructor of MyString get uninitialized array of chars. Then you trying to get the length of the string, but `strlen` just looping through chars of the string looking for `0` char. As we don't know what content uninitialized array of chars might have, we don't know what length `strlen` could return. It can even go further than array boundary and crash your program with segfault. But I can say for sure, after that there's not enough space in from.stringPtr to hold the string you want to copy in it.

So, use `from.stringPtr = new char[stringLen+1];` or better `from = MyString(*this);` since you have copy constructor already.